# Distinguishing data-addresses of I2C chips [case ADS1015]

Tags: i2c, pi-3b+

I'm trying to learn reading out I2C chips, but somehow I can't figure out how to find the right data addresses.

I bought a water level sensor and a ADS1015 ADC[foto below]. They are connected via I2C to the RPI. The RPI seems to be configured correctly, as i2cdetect -y 1 shows that an I2C chip is present at 0x48. The water sensor LED lights up so it has power. I expect the chip to have more than 1 value, and should therefore supply i2cget with the address:

> i2cget -y 1 0x48 ***address***

It should be in the [datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/ads1015.pdf), but I don't get where it tells me the address. I tried looping over all addresses, some give an error, some a value (128, 133, 0, ...).

*How do I figure out where the voltage is stored on the I2C chip?*

*Also, the ADS1015 has 4 channels, are these combined in one I2C chip, or should i2cdetect list 4 channels?*

Thanks!

[image: wiring]

Comment: That doesn't seem to be an easy chip to work with.  Trial and error seems your best bet but using the Quick Start as a guide (page 8 of the PDF).  I would google for the chip name followed by a programming language of your choice.  Then look through the code to see how the chip is configured and read.

Comment: The [Adafruit tests](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_ADS1x15) help to see that the configuration does work, so that's nice.

Answer (score 2):

read http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1015-q1.pdf

paragraph 8.5.1.1 for I2C addressing

perhaps this datasheet will also answer your other question

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as advised by Jan Hans, the use of the ADDR pin is clever.

[image]